# Necessary Schnorr signature non-interactive challenge bindings

Tags: schnorr-signature

Some implementations of a Schnorr signature will determine the challenge as follows:

$c=H(kG \mathbin\| X \mathbin\| m)==H(rG+cX \mathbin\| X \mathbin\| m)$, where:

$c$ is the challenge
$m$ is the message being signed
$X$ is the public key of the signer such that $X=xG$
$G$ is a well-known base point
$x$ is the private key of the signer
$r$ is the response to the challenge, calculated as $r=k-cx$
$k$ is a uniformly random nonce

However, some Schnorr signatures do not bind the public key $X$ of the signer into the challenge hash. Thus, $c=H(kG \mathbin\| m)$.

What possible attacks are prevented by including $X$ in the challenge hash?

Note that the signature could either be communicated as the pair $(c,r)$, or as the pair $(K,r)$ where $K=kG$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rather contrived scenario, but suppose that there are two verification keys $X_1=x_1G$ and $X_2=x_2G$ belonging to two distinct signers and suppose that the attacker does not know either $x_1$ nor $x_2$ but does know the difference between them, say $x_1=x_2+b$. They could then use a signature from signer 1 to forge a signature from signer 2 on the same piece of data (and vice-versa) with the unbound scheme.

To do this they'd take the $r_1$ from signer 1's signature and replace it with $r_2=r_1+bc$.